# Cocoa framework development: sharing between projects

Tags: cocoa, xcode, frameworks, code-sharing

I am currently developing a handful of similar Cocoa desktop apps. In an effort to share code between them, I have identified a set of core classes and functions that can be common across all of these applications. I would like to bundle this common code into a framework which all of my current applications (and any future ones) can link against.

Now, here's the hard part: I'm going to be developing this framework as I go, so I need each of my desktop apps to have a reference to it, but I want to be able to edit the framework source code from within each of the app projects and have the framework automatically rebuilt as required.

For example, let's say I have the Xcode project for DesktopAppNumberOne open, and I decide that one of my framework classes needs to be changed. I would like to:

1. Open and edit the source file for that framework class without having to open the framework project in Xcode.
2. Hit "build" on DesktopAppNumberOne, and see the framework rebuilt first (because one of its sources has changed), then see parts of DesktopAppNumberOne rebuilt (because one of the frameworks it links against has changed).

I can see how to do this with only one app and one framework, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it with multiple apps that share a single framework.

Has anyone had success with this approach? Am I perhaps going about this the wrong way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say you can see how todo it with one project.. but you don't say how. Anyway, it's no different for two, three, or more projects. Please explain how you would do it.

Comment: For one project I would include all of the framework source files, add a target for the framework, and make the app target dependent on the framework target. Easy enough. Doing that with more than one project involves a lot of repetition. If I add files to the framework, for example, I'll have to add those files in each of the other projects as well. Same goes for changing a build setting, renaming a file, etc.

Comment: Conceptually, I would like to be able to include the framework as a complete Xcode *project* within each of my app projects, if that makes any sense at all. In this way, each of the app projects would depend on the framework project, but the framework project itself would be a self-contained entity that only needs to be edited in one place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make an XCode Project for you framework.

In the 'Groups & Files' Panel > See the Blue Project Icon at the very top left? Drag and drop that into the 'Groups & Files' Panel of any other project you like.

So, make an app project, and drag in the project icon from your framework project.

**CMD-i on your app target**. Here you set your dependency on the framework and Link against it.

*A few points*

Linking multiple apps to one framework can be stressfull. You will either need to install your framework into /Library/Frameworks or equivalent or bundle up into each app.

For development purposes, i find setting a custom, common build directory for each of the projects eases things. I set each project to build into **/Code/Build/Debug**. This means that framework search path for debug build can be $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR. For your release builds you will still have some work todo with install paths, rpaths, etc. Pain in the Ass!

XConfig files are your friends. The Open source google mac toolbox stuff is a good example of how to use them. You will probably need at least a **Project_debug.xconfig**, **Project_release.xconfig**, **Target_framework.xconfig**, **Target_application.xconfig**.

Comment: Looks promising. Thank you! I'll give it a shot

Comment: Cool. This will do the trick nicely! I had no idea you could simply drop in a project as a dependency.

Comment: incase you don't already know about it - With complex projects with multiple targets, etc. I always enable the "Target Membership" column (Cntrl Click on 'Groups & Files'). I couldn't live without it.